# Utilizar variável de um component em outro - Angular IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic, component

Estou iniciando com Angular e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de passar o valor de uma variável para outro component para ser utilizada posteriormente.

```
defineDificuldade(dificuldade) {
    console.log('Selected level ~~> ', dificuldade);
    this.userChoiceLevel = dificuldade;
  }
```

Esse trecho de código pertence ao arquivo userlevel.page.ts

Gostaria de passar o valor da variável userChoiceLevel para outro component para utilizar nos meus métodos

Tentei algo com @Input mas não consegui aplicar de forma funcional:

```
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" color="primary" expand= "full" shape= "round" fill='outline' *ngIf="selectedLevel" (click)="defineDificuldade(selectedLevel)" [userChoiceLevel]='userChoiceLevel'>Começar</ion-button>
```

O problema acontece por eu não saber o que fazer com essa [userChoiceLevel]='userChoiceLevel' depois de coloca-la no HTML

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu poderia passar o valor de uma variável para outro component?

A tela que estou trabalhando e desejo passar dados para as outras é a seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que voce precisa, voce pode configurar as rotas para passagem de parametro entre os componentes utilizando um serviço.

Nos parâmetros de rota, você deve transmitir apenas os dados que deseja que sejam refletidos na barra de URL do navegador.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch : 'full'},
  {path : 'heroes', component : HeroDetailComponent, data : {some_data : 'some value'}}
];
```

Passagem dos dados:

```
class HeroDetailComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```